# Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider

Tags: hibernate, deployment, jboss

I'm trying to deploy my springboot app in jboss 6.4.7 but the console freeze with this :

```
Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
```

and the deployment fail. I have added a jboss-deployments-structure on my project which contains this :

```
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jpa" />
        <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>

    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />  
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.ext" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" /> 
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager"/> 
        <module name="jcl-over-slf4j"/>  

        <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
        <module name="javaee.api" />
        <module name="javax.api" />

    </exclusions>
```

When I remove this : `<subsystem name="logging"/>`, it works but uses JBoss module (and I don't want that). 
Any Idea ?

**Edit**

In fact, I have an EAR with multiples war/jar. And some of the jar are using persistence.xml. But the problem comes when I try to start my app.war with other .war/.jar in the EAR.

If I remove the logging exlusion in the jboss-deployment-structure of the ear, it works and in the log I have this :

```
Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

The app starts but using jboss's logging module.

Do I have to exclude something else in my jboss-deployment-structure ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For testing environments you should use an in-memory database like HSQLDB or H2. Creating and dropping such database is lightning fast so it will speed-up your testing considerably.

For system integration tests, you might want to connect to a production-like database server, but that clone database server should be collocated to the testing environment to avoid unnecessary networking delays or slow connections.

Are you cleanly shutting down your JBoss instance? All of the threads   related to slow periodic recovery had to do with unclean shutdown and startup. I also suggest updated to the very latest JDBC driver, as there has been at least one fix related to transaction recovery.

Try to set the following properties in your persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.<Dialect_Class_name>" />
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false" />
```

Comment: My persistence.xml has already this <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" /> I have added the second property too and still get the same issue.  Can you look the update now please. Thanks :)

Comment: comment this line and check:

<! - <prop Key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"> true </ prop> ->